# Using express without a template engine

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Is it possible to create an express (node) application without the need for a template engine such as jade or ejs. I've got a large final year project at university and i'm going to be using node, express, socket.io, mongoDB and websockets. I don't want to burden myself with having to learn a templating language too!

**By default express uses jade**
-t, --template   add template  support (jade|ejs). default=jade

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an express (node) application without the need for a template engine such as jade or ejs

Yes it is. You can just use HTML. Or just use EJS. EJS is a superset of HTML.

> I don't want to burden myself with having to learn a templating language too!

You can learn a templating language in a day. It's really going to help you. Just do it. It's worth it.

Comment: you've always got an answer when it comes to anything JavaScript related, and your answers are always to the point and informative. Thanks!

Comment: @JackBrown [You can come chat for quick questions](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js)

Comment: i think it's not about learning a new template language, i just think using a template engine would mess up your html pages. Imagine if you got lots well-designed html pages, you got to translate them into a wholly new template format, that's bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate to how to use HTML as the view engine?

Comment: Well a templating engine is just there to help developers. For many languages, its not easy to match the backend code with the frontend, however, with node.js, I truly feel that the developer can stay with native front end code. However, if you develop with multiple languages, the templating system will do wonders in keeping a consistent design.

Comment: @Raynos On reading your answer, it still doesn't help on `how` to use express without a template engine. I guess the OP wanted a yes/no answer but it will be really helpful if you can explain the `how` part.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to avoid learning another template language, you might want to give underscore templates a try. They're just javascript, which you're going to be learning anyway.

[documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)

You can set it up with:

```
app.register('.html', {
    compile: function(str, options){
        var compiled = require('underscore').template(str);
        return function(locals) {
            return compiled(locals);
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this would be to replace the default app.get('/')... line with the following.
Then put all the magic in index.html. This will at least work quite well for a single page app.

with the following

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
var readFile = "index.html";
var fileContents = fs.readFileSync(readFile);

response.send(fileContents.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best option right now is to use ejs (engine) and configure it to accept and render html:

```
app.set('views', path.join(*__dirname*, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // template engine
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile); // turn engine to use html
```

Note: All your views or templates have the `.html` extension.